# Dynamic Dropdown Menu using 'switch' Javascript Not Working

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, combobox, switch-statement

I have this script at the document level (simplified) on a PDF:

```
function SetFieldValues(){
var Model = this.getField("Model");
var Armor = this.getField("Armor");
var Winch = this.getField("Winch");
var Test1 = this.getField("Test1");
var Test2 = this.getField("Test2");

if(event.willCommit)    {
switch(event.value) {

case "015305676":
    Model.value = "AMK23";
    Armor.value = "YES";
    Winch.value = "NO";
    Test1.setItems[("Not Applicable")];
    Test2.setItems[("-", "Serviceable", "Unserviceable")];
    break;
}}}
```

This event is kicked off by the Custom Keystroke on the form's initiating dropdown list:

```
if( event.willCommit )
{
if(event.value == "-")
  this.resetForm(["Model","Armor","Winch"]);
else
  SetFieldValues(event.value)
}
```

All the fields update appropriately (Model, Armor, and Winch) however, the "Test" combo boxes do not populate as expected.

I then tried it a different way with this (which I thought would be genius using an array ...pfft... I was wrong):

```
function SetFieldValues(){
var Model = this.getField("Model");
var Armor = this.getField("Armor");
var Winch = this.getField("Winch");

const ArmorArray = [field='Test1', field='Test2'];
var ArmorArray;

var CheckOptionsY = {
  Yes: [["-"],["Serviceable"],["Unserviceable"]],
};
var CheckOptionsN = {
  No: [["Not Applicable"]],
};
if(event.willCommit)
{
switch(event.value) {

case "015305676":
    Model.value = "AMK23";
    Armor.value = "YES";
    Winch.value = "NO";
    ArmorArray.setItems[(CheckOptionsY)];
    break;
}}}
```

Again, the fields update no problem (Model, Armor, and Winch) but the "Test" fields do not update with the combo box list options. What did I do wrong? How can I get these "Test" combo boxes to load with the appropriate 'Yes' / 'No' options?

Comment: I got the first code fixed. Evidently it is how you use the brackets: 
    Test1.setItems[("Not Applicable")];
    Test2.setItems[("-", "Serviceable", "Unserviceable")];

Should use:

    Test1.setItems(["Not Applicable")];
    Test2.setItems(["-", "Serviceable", "Unserviceable")];

Amazing that brackets could effect the execution.

Comment: What about the array? Can anyone solve using the array? I really need that to work.